# getting reference to JS objects inside ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am loading an html page through ajax which contains a JS object. How do you get a reference to the object inside the freshly loaded (child) page to the parent page?

Parent:

```
//parent.html

<script>

    function ParentObject() {
        this.children = new Array();
    }

    var aParentObject = new ParentObject();

    $.get('/url/to/child.html', function(data) {
        $("#child-div").html(data);
    });

</script>
```

Child:

```
//child.html

<div>Some html element</div>

...

<script>
    function ChildObject() {
        this.someProperty = "I'm a Child";
    }

    var aChildObject = new ChildObject();
</script>
```

Comment: Try console.log(aChildObject) after your html function. You should be able to view the child object instance I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use var when you declare new variable

```
var aChildObject = new ChildObject();
```

When you append a html containing a jscript the script will execute and you will get reference after that point. So you must ensure that you access the child variable after you insert it.

```
$.get('/url/to/child.html', function(data) {
    $("#child-div").html(data);
    //Access your child here
    alert(aParentObject.someProperty);
});
```

Comment: Did you mean `alert(aChildObject.someProperty)`?

Comment: aah Yes, sorry, alert(aChildObject.someProperty)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `.load()` in place of `.get()`. With `.load()` you can specify a selector for the "child" page to pull back a specific part that you want to retrieve.

Assuming that child.html's `div` has `id="child-div"`:

```
//parent.html

<script>

    function ParentObject() {
        this.children = new Array();
    }

    aParentObject = new ParentObject();

    $("#child-div").load('/url/to/child.html #child-div');

</script>
```

See the "Loading Page Fragments" section here: http://api.jquery.com/load/